# POST Request Receive Files

Tags: javascript, file, post, http-headers

I'm using [Oboe](http://oboejs.com/) for a client POST request to a server. It's a POST request because we're sending a lot of data (image data) to be converted into a zip of PDFs and returned. So the server returns a zip file with an attachment disposition, but when testing it nothing happens when it receives the response. Here's the Oboe request:

```
promiseOboe({
  url: configuration.rootApiUrl + 'pdffile/download/separated',
  method: 'POST',
  body: { pdfs: appState.pdfs }
}).then(function(data) {
  // Should I do something here?
}).catch(function(err){console.log(err)});
```

Here's the response header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=Filename.zip
Content-Length:22
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
Date:Thu, 05 Nov 2015 19:27:38 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcc2NvdHRoXERvY3VtZW50c1xBbGxfQ29kZVxFZGl0UGRmU2VydmVyXEVkaXRQZGZTZXJ2ZXJcYXBpXHBkZmZpbGVcZG93bmxvYWRcc2VwYXJhdGVk?=
```

Am I missing something? Should I do something in the `.then()` fucntion? Why doesn't the browser receive the files in its standard way of downloading them?

Comment: If I understood correct, Oboe only works with JSON, not binary files (zip) which seems to be very strange case. What are you going to do with zip file in Javascript?

Comment: @hindmost Thanks for that insight. I want to offer the zip file to the user to download.

Comment: _I want to offer the zip file to the user to download._ You don't need AJAX (and Oboe) in this case, just show him (her) a link to the file.

Comment: @hindmost I'll fill out my question. The file is generated from data sent in the POST request, so it doesn't exist until the route is hit. It's a POST request because we're sending a lot of data (image data) to the server. Is the proper solution to send back a link/id and then hit a GET route to actually get it?

Comment: You can use `location.replace` or [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) to redirect user to download a file.

Comment: So that will require a second request right? Because using either of those is making a GET request right?

Comment: Yes, both of them will result in GET request, but it will be done autom'ly. You only have to pass needed URL.

Comment: Ok, but I should be doing a POST request right, because I'm sending large amounts of data and URLs have size limits? If that is true it seems to rule out the possibility of using `window.open` or `location.replace`.

Comment: We have already agreed that there will be two requests, isn't it? 1) POST request sending data and receiving file URL; 2) GET request (by `window.open` or `location.replace`) to received URL.